# Identifying products

Tags: phenols

How to determine the major and minor products in a reaction? What factors are useful to do so?
For ex: Nitration of phenols, gives the ortho nitro phenol as the the major product and para nitro phenol as the minor, while Nitrosation of phenols give para nitroso phenol as the major product and ortho nitriso phenol.

Comment: This is a very broad question as the major product of a reaction may depend upon multiple factors each different for each reaction.

Comment: It is almost like asking *How to learn organic chemistry from a 1 page answer ?* The  right answer is even shorter: *Study many textbooks, books and articles and gain years of experience in chemistry.* // I guess the 80-20 rule is applicable even here: Understanding 80% of cases takes 20% of effort.

Comment: You won't know until you run the reaction. You may be able to predict the likely course of the reaction based on pre-existing literature and you may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The main factors used to determine the major and minor products are:

1. Stability of products
2. Kinetics of the reaction
3. Reaction conditions
4. Catalyst used , etc.

I just gave out a few examples but, there are hundreds of other factors which you can only learn by practice.